# MS Office Home and Student

Tags: microsoft-office

If I buy MS Office Home and Student when I install it can I just activate it like anything else, or do I actually need to provide my student details? How do they verify if your a student when you have the CD?

Also does it ever expire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Office Home and Student is just like any other retail edition of Office apart from it says "Not for commercial use" on the box. (That is if you bought retail and not OEM).

What you are thinking of is educational licensing which is separate (and can be cheaper) but the full editions e.g. Office Professional / Ultimate.

If you are a student, you may be able to purchase through [one of the promotions](http://www.microsoft.com/student/office/en-gb/default.aspx) which is a better deal than Home and Student. (Select country through the top right of that page).

Edit-

The software does not expire or licence stop when you are no longer a student. You just have to be a student to qualify for it. Once you have it, you own it for life.